# css div auto fill all available space inside of document

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a div that is the document's width and height.
Minus 10 pixels all around as in this picture:
http://screensnapr.com/v/a9JWIf.png

But every time I pad or add to the margin of the body or outer div, it adds to the document's total height and shows scrollbars.

How can I make a div auto fill all available size without extending the size of the document?

edit: any negative margins do not effect the divs total size

Here is a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ZRz32/6/

As you can see, it extends the document height.
I need it to stay the document's size minus ten pixels all around

Comment: could you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or provide some sample code?

Comment: Try this: http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

Comment: @Alp I dont need it to stick to the bottom. I need it to be the document height minus a set amount of pixels.

Answer (score 5):

I think that it's the easiest way to do it:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#main {
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: green;
}

<div id="container">
    <div id="main"></div>
</div>
```

I updated your Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZRz32/7/).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZRz32/9/ this is what it looks like when you put content, you solution does not work with absolute.

Comment: @Drake, based off what you said, this is in fact your best solution. The reason it doesnt work is because you put content inside of both the main and container div. You should ONLY put the content inside the main div.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hpLBS/1/) example.

Essentially, you need to set your containing element to `width:100%` and give it 10px of padding on left and right (`padding:0 10px`). Then, you can set your inner elements to `width:100%` and they will only go to within 10px of the max document width.

Comment: The issue isnt just the width. That solution does not work for height. You can test it on your fiddle example.

Answer (score 0):

You could try either giving the `div` a `width` and `height` of `95-99%`, but that won't always guarantee a space of 10px. You could do the 10px of padding on either the `body` or the `div` and just assign `overflow:hidden` to the `body` if you're planning on having all your content in one place.

Comment: Yes percents less than 100 are not what I am looking for. I dont plan on hiding the scrollbars since they will be needed.

Comment: If they'll be needed then why can't they be made with the padding? If only the vertical bar will be used then you can do `overflow-x:hidden;` and that'll eliminate the horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: The issue isnt just the horizontal scrollbar, its both. Hiding the problem doesnt fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it fixed over the page, you could use positioning: `<div style="position:fixed; top: 10px; left: 10px; right: 10px; bottom: 10px; background-color: rgba(155, 155, 155, .6);">Some text</div>`

Comment: Since the background will have a gradient, fixed positioning will not suffice.